# PHP automatically close window after timeout

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was able to close the window.  But with the timeout, it does not seem to work.

This test.php was called by the submit button's action on another window.  If I remarked out all window closing script lines, then this "Sending ... This window will close itself after sending." will show up.

This `echo "<script>window.close();</script>";` will close this window without showing any echo.  The other 3 lines, all I see is a blank window and not being closed at all.  Only on the Chrome I got a Server 500 error.  I tried on Firefox, Safari, and Chrome.

Any suggestions?

test.php contains:

```
<?php

    echo "Sending ... This window will close itself after sending.";

    echo "<script>window.close();</script>";  // this line works

//    echo "<script>setTimeout("window.close()", 5000);</script>";

//    <script type="text/javascript">setTimeout("window.close();", 3000);</script>
//    echo "<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout( function() { window.close(); }, 3000);</script>"

?>
```

Comment: `setTimeout("window.close()", 5000);` worked for me; *"it does not seem to work."* doesn't clarify what the problem is.

Comment: what window are you referring to? Can't close windows that aren't opened by script

Comment: It worked for me too, on which browser did you try?

Comment: updated my answer too

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout("window.close();", 2000);</script>
```

Tell me if this works, of course change 2000 to what you want ;)

Comment: better yet, setTimeout(window.close, 2000); (function reference instead of string literal, and no benchmark expensive eval() )

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a function to setTimeout().

Try this:

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){ window.close();}, 5000);</script>
```

UPDATE on your update:
Error 500 means "Internal server error", there is something wrong with your script, not the resulting page.

I assume that you are not posting the real script, but there is something else wrong in it besides what you output.
Did you really wrote double quotes inside PHP string?
Because what you are really doing is writing a compile error, something like that is illegal PHP code:

```
echo "something "quoted" something";
```

I still suggest you to write a proper function and not a string, but if you must, at least escape the double quote, or use the single quote to start PHP constant string if you don't have to parse variables in it.

```
echo 'something "quoted" something';//I prefer this
```

or

```
echo "something \"quoted\" something";
//but this still works, altough parser will try to find variable names
```